# PhoneGap + Database How save a result in the database & how use data stock in a page

Tags: sql, cordova, sample, squeryl

My uderstanding of Javascript is really limited. I have a simple calculation to make. `A` `B` and `C` are 3 inputs numbers and I need the result `D` in the database iOS for future use, using Phonegap and jQuery.

```
[ (A-10) / (200/B) ] + [ (C/10) x ((10xB)/45)] = C
```

This is my simple javascript

```
function test(){
  a=Number(document.calculator.entree1.value);
  b=Number(document.calculator.entree2.value);
  c=Number(document.calculator.entree3.value);
  d=((a-10)/(200/b))+((c/10)*((10*b)/45))
  document.calculator.total.value=Math.round(d);
}
```

My question is how I could stock this data result `Math.round(d);` in the phone gap database and use it again in a daily page result?

Thanks.